# What is meant by Equivalent Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

What is meant by the electrical equivalent circuit of a machine like transformer, generator and motor.

Is there a general definition of Equivalent circuit?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_circuit

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because lack of googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalent circuit is a model of a more complicated system, that preserves the most important behaviour.

For instance, charge needs to be supplied to a FET's gate drain junction to turn it on, and during this time, the voltage across the junction rises. This behaviour is very much like having a linear capacitor between the terminals. The equivalent circuit of a FET will often show this as a capacitor, to aid understanding.